# What is the design pattern for asserting a property of an item in a list, in test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I would like to assert (in rspec really) that at least one item in the `tags` list is non-public.

```
it 'lets you select non-public tags' do
  get :new
  flag = false
  assigns(:tags).each do |tag|
    if tag.is_public == false
      flag = true
    end
  end
  flag.should eql true
end
```

What is a better, idiomatic way of doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a million ways to do this:

```
# are any tags not public?
flag = assigns(:tags).any? { |tag| !tag.is_public }
flag.should eql true
```

or

```
# Are none of the tags public?
flag = assigns(:tags).none?(&:is_public)
flag.should eql true
```

or

```
# Find the first non-public tag?
flag = assigns(:tags).find { |tag| !tag.is_public}
flag.should_not eql nil
```

Comment: The middle one (none of the flags public) does not give the same result in all cases as the OP code.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of options here. Perhaps:

```
assigns(:tags).reject { |tag| tag.is_public }.should_not be_empty
```